How to make buttons that will save user input
I am writing a program that saves user data. It is necessary to write code for the “Save” buttons so that the data entered by the user is saved (preferably in a sqlite3 database). I just understood Tkinter, I still have to deal with the database SQLite, but I don’t have time. Help quickly please. I see that everyone is just writing databases, but I can’t understand them yet, but I need to finish my micro project by tomorrow.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3 as sql

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Saver data')
win.geometry('390x310')
win.resizable(False, False)

def delete_catalog():
    selection = catalogs_listbox.curselection()
    try:
        catalogs_listbox.delete(selection[0])
    except IndexError:
        messagebox.showinfo('Attention!', 'Choose element you want to remove')

def add_catalog():
    new_catalog = catalog_entry.get()
    if len(new_catalog) > 0:
        catalogs_listbox.insert(0, new_catalog)
        catalog_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    if len(new_catalog) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo('Attention!', 'Enter the folder name!')

intro = tk.Label(text='')
intro.configure(font=('Times New Roman', 11))
intro.place(x=5, y=5)

catalog_entry = tk.Entry(width=21)
catalog_entry.configure(font=('Times New Roman', 15))
catalog_entry.place(x=51, y=30)
add_catalog_btn = tk.Button(text="Add", width=9, command=add_catalog)
add_catalog_btn.place(y=30, x=268)

catalogs_listbox = tk.Listbox(width=29, height=9)
catalogs_listbox.configure(font=('Times New Roman', 15))
catalogs_listbox.place(x=49, y=60)

def on_select(event):
    widget = event.widget
    selection = widget.curselection()
    i = int(widget.curselection()[0])
    value = widget.get(i)
    if selection:
        data_window = tk.Tk()
        data_window.title(f'Data for {value}')
        data_window.geometry('390x65')
        data_window.resizable(False, False)

        login_label = tk.Label(master=data_window, text='Login')
        login_label.place(x=15, y=5)
        login_entry = tk.Entry(master=data_window, width=30)
        login_entry.place(x=100, y=5)

        password_label = tk.Label(master=data_window, text='Password')
        password_label.place(x=15, y=35)
        password_entry = tk.Entry(master=data_window, width=30)
        password_entry.place(x=100, y=35)

        save_datas = tk.Button(master=data_window, text='Save')
        save_datas.place(x=300, y=15)

        data_window.mainloop()

catalogs_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_select)

save_program = tk.Button(master=win, text='Save')
save_program.place(x=200, y=278)

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=catalogs_listbox.yview)
scrollbar.grid_forget()
catalogs_listbox["yscrollcommand"] = scrollbar.set

delete_catalog = tk.Button(text="Delete", command=delete_catalog)
delete_catalog.configure(font=('Times New Roman', 10))
delete_catalog.place(x=286, y=278)

win.mainloop()


SO is not a code writting service, and that appears to be what you are asking for.  How to ask

You are creating two Tk() windows. Try changing data_window = tk.Tk() to data_window = tk.Toplevel(win) and remove data_window.mainloop().
